# Microsoft media streaming services - Can I use it for Adaptive Streaming?

Tags: silverlight, streaming, video-streaming

I have Microsoft Expression Encoder 2, and I encoded a video for Adaptive Streaming. Can I then upload the files to the Microsoft media streaming services (http://silverlight.live.com) and use Adaptive Streaming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No - you have to use the [IIS Media Services](http://www.iis.net/media) on your own IIS server or with a server from a content delivery network that supports Smooth Streaming (most of them do).